# Write text on image in objective-c iPhone, Font size of simulator different from on iPhone itself

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uiimage, retina-display

I'm having something really weird going, I'm adding caption to an image and everything works fine on simulator but on the device itself the font is really small...

I have a problem when using this code :

```
-(UIImage*) drawTextOnPic:(NSString*) bottomText
         inImage:(UIImage*)  image
{

UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:48];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];

CGRect = CGRectMake(10.0f,10.0f,image.size.width-20.0f, image.size.height);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(2.5f, 2.5f), 5.0f);


[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[bottomText drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

Does someone know why it works only on simulator as I expected? BTW, I'm using the SDK for iOS6, Can it be something there?
Is it something with the retina display? How to fix that?

Comment: Output all of the things that define your font size (`CAPTION_FONT_SIZE`,`image.size`) and make sure they are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose the default font size (on my case it's 48) and then checked the image size according to some ref size (in my case 640x480), I did that by sqrtf(area(a)/area(ref)) then multiply this result on font size.
That's the only way it works for me.

Hope that would help others...

Comment: hello Idan. can I ask a sample code for your calculation. I'm confuse by your formula. thanks in advance

Comment: @user3818576 That's a very old solution not sure it's the best way to calc that. The formula is easy it just makes the difference between your new screen area (area a) to the screen you used for the font size (area ref).
So to make this more understandable, If area 'a' has width of Aw and hight of Ah then it's area is Aw x Ah. If you used 640x480 for reference size than the equation would be Sqrt((Aw x Ah)/(640x480)). Sqrt mean square root.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, you should be using the extended call to pass in screen scale, like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
```

That will create the image context at the scale of your screen. Note that the second argument, here `YES`, is whether or not you need the image to be opaque. If there's transparency in your image, set this to `NO`.

Comment: That doesn't work. Still the fonts appears to be really small when the image is huge.
What I did is figuring out how big the fonts should be according to the pic size and resize them. It's really not elegant so if you have some other solution I would love to try it.

Comment: You might need to multiply font size by the screen scale.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Drawing text on image
+ (UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*)text withColor:(UIColor *) textColor inImage:(UIImage*)image atPoint:(CGPoint)point {

    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [textColor set];
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```