# iOS UITextView generate a screenshot of the selected text - is it possible using TextKit or any other method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, textkit

In my app and using Objective-C I need to implement the following functionality if possible. I would like to know if it is possible to generate a screenshot of the selected text from a UITextView. I know it sounds like a weird question but it is an important and a required functionality.

I know how to just create a screenshot programmatically but would like the region of the screenshot to be selectable based on the selected text, I hope you know what I mean.

Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion : get selected step -> Write text in UIImage -> save that canvas. Your work is done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298266/write-text-on-image-in-objective-c-iphone-font-size-of-simulator-different-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you:

```
NSString *selectedText = [textView textInRange:textView.selectedTextRange];
NSDictionary *textOptions = @{NSFontAttributeName : textView.font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : textView.textColor};
CGSize textSize = [selectedText sizeWithAttributes:textOptions];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(textSize, NO, 0);
[selectedText drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, textSize.width, textSize.height) withAttributes:textOptions];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thats just perfect, thank you so much. This is exactly what I was hoping for. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to supposed your `UITextView` is `self.textView`, using `quartz` you can do:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.textView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

[self.textView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *newImageWithMyTextView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

More info search Core Graphics in Apple docs

Comment: Please read carefully question - @Will ask about screenshot only selected text, not whole textview

Comment: Hi I just wanted to thank you Onik IV for your attempt as well, however Vitaliy is correct as I tested both.